# Can parse date DateTime.Parse

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, datetime, mobile-application

1. This line is parsed DateTime.Parse("08/08/2000 00:00:00")
2. This line isn't parsed DateTime.Parse("08/24/2000 00:00:00")

Question is very simple and stupid, I'm sorry but can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a localization issue, where it's trying to parse in day/month/year format, and you're assuming it's month/day/year format.

Comment: I tried following format: DateTime.Parse("24/08/2000 00:00:00") and got an error instantly that format is wrong. It's so weird

Comment: @Richard It's not weird, you just need to Google better. In UK we use `dd-mm-yyyy` but in USA it is `mm-dd-yyyy`. There are literally hundreds, if not thousands of questions with the same problem on here.

Comment: @DavidG what format should I use to make in wordlwide-friendly?

Comment: There is no worldwide friendly, everywhere does it differently.